# Dart search, add and remove from data model List

Tags: dart, collections

you suppose this is my class as a sample code:

```
class SelectedPage {
  final String username;
  final String pageProfileImage;

  SelectedPage(this.username, this.pageProfileImage);
}
```

in this class i want to add model data as `SelectedPage` when its not in `_selectedPage` list and when this model is in the list i should remove that from list, for example which this code is not correct

```
void main() {
  const String pageName = 'my name';
  final List<SelectedPage> pages = [];

  final SelectedPage newPage =
      SelectedPage(pageName, 'assets/images/my_pic.jpg');
  pages.add(newPage);

  if (pages.where((currentName) => currentName.username.contains(pageName)) !=
      null) {
    pages.remove(newPage);
    print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>> REMOVED');
  } else {
    pages.add(newPage);
    print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ADDED');
  }
}

class SelectedPage {
  final String username;
  final String pageProfileImage;

  SelectedPage(this.username, this.pageProfileImage);
}
```

i want to search `'my name'` in `page.selectedPages` which that is `SelectedPage` class model data, if `'my name'` exist into model i should remove that from list, otherwise that should be added to list as model

Comment: what is `page.selectedPages.map` used for? if you want to find if something exists use `contains` or `where`

Comment: @pskink thats instance of `ChangeNotifierSelectablePage`

Comment: @pskink `page.selectedPages.contains(pageName)` is not correct and added to list always

Comment: i asked why you use `List.map()` method? do you know when it should be used?

Comment: @pskink i try to search row by row in list and check current saved model equal with `my name`

Comment: @pskink i changed post contain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it will result in the object being ***always*** removed, because `where()` will return a `List` with the result for the query you've just made, even if it's an empty `List`.

So, if you want to do it that way, you need to query and then check if the `List` is empty or not. If it is, then you don't have *that* element, if not, then you have.

```
List query = pages.where((currentName) => currentName.username.contains(pageName)).toList();

  if (query.isNotEmpty) {
    pages.remove(newPage);
    print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>> REMOVED');
  } else {
    pages.add(newPage);
    print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ADDED');
  }
}
```